# Unlock Aspect Ratio from Prompted Input

Tags: vba, excel, aspect-ratio

I'm getting a compile error on `img.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse`. All I'm trying to do is unlock the aspect ratio of the image that is being imported from the user. I would assume I'm not using the proper syntax, any help would be great

```
Sub ChangeImage()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            Dim img As Object
            Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))

            img.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

            img.Left = 141
            img.Top = 925

            img.Width = 600
            img.Height = 251
        Else
            Debug.Print "Prompt closed"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187148/resizing-image-in-vba-maintaining-aspect-ratio/47187290#47187290

Comment: @braX Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't really help my issue, as I was declaring it as `Object` when it should have been a `Picture` as cyboashu has correctly answered it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to insert picture, declare the type as `Picture` and not as `Object`. Use LockAspectRatio is available under the `ShapeRange` property.

```
Sub ChangeImage()
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .ButtonName = "Submit"
            .Title = "Select an image file"
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

            If .Show = -1 Then
                Dim img As Picture '/ Declare as Picture
                Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))


               '/ Use ShapeRange to toogle aspect ratio
               img.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse


                img.Left = 141
                img.Top = 925

                img.Width = 600
                img.Height = 251
            Else
                Debug.Print "Prompt closed"
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```